# Databinding in AS3 to a slider

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am creating a datagrid in AS3, and want to pass the value of a slider to an item renderer

```
var column : MyDataGridColumn = new MyDataGridColumn();
column.sliderValue = mySlider.value;
...
```

This works fine initially, but when I move the slider, I would like the datagrid to assign the new value to the column.

This worked fine when I created the datagrid in MXML and bound the slider value like this

```
<local:MyDataGridColumn
 sliderValue="{mySlider.value}"/>
```

This gets re-evaluated and re-assigned everytime the slider changes. The AS3 version not.

I tried it with a bindable function, and assign the function result to the column, but it did not work. Any ideas?
Thx,

Martin

Comment: `<local:MyDataGridColumn sliderValue="{mySlider.value}"/>` I don't understand how this worked - can you bind a value to a column? shouldn't you be binding it to the dataProvider?

Comment: Does MyDataGridColumn extend DataGridColumn or ListCollectionView?

Comment: I bind this value to the column, cause I extended the DataGridColumn, which performs background coloring based on the slider value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set a change event handler on the slider and manually update the column.sliderValue when the change event is dispatched.  Something like:

```
mySlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, function(event:SliderEvent):void {
  column.sliderValue = mySlider.value;
});
```

Comment: So I would need to loop through all the created columns of this datagrid to update this value?
In the end I went again for the MXML solution - is not so nice because its more sparse, but the data binding is just a lot more flexible.
Thanks!